PHP 7.3, Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2017, PDO: error "No ODBC error was found"
I'm getting an error inconsistently.
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $core->server . ";Database=webcontent;", $uid, $pwd);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ODBC Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    // Fetch all result sets
    $resultSets = [];
    do {
        $resultSets[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset()) ; <<< ERROR THROWS HERE
    

    return $resultSets;

The error message is:
No ODBC error was found

The sql in question does return multiple result sets. It runs without error if I use sqlsrv_query (though only some of the recordsets come back - that's another issue.) There are no print statements. None of the queries comes back blank. SET NOCOUNT ON is at the top of every procedure.
I'll run the code once and get everything back, nice and neat. I run it again a minute later, it fails. If I made an alteration to the query - change '2' in the criteria to '4', it runs fine. Change the 4 back to 2, it runs fine. It'll run fine a dozen times, then start failing.
Any help?
(...Yes, I know we should be on PHP 8+, but there's a lot of old code that needs to be brought up to date and throws errors if it's not, and there are other things more imperative right now.)

I don't think anything could help other than already existing resources

Try: SET NOCOUNT ON; somewhere on the top perhaps?

@siggemannen SET NOCOUNT ON is at the top of every stored procedure being called.

@YourCommonSense I spent quite a long time searching the internet for this issue before posting, and have already visited every site behind that search.

It's not that I say you didn't. What I say, it's just unlikely someone will tell you something new compared to these bug reports

@YourCommonSense Then why does SO exist, one wonders. In any event, thanks for the time.

Surely, SO exists to answer only one single question of yours. And if SO can't help with it, then of course it's entirely useless (:

@YourCommonSense Didn't say that, didn't even imply it. I'm sorry you're having a bad day, mate. Cheers.
